Inserting string instead of values in dynamic SQL
I am trying to log parameter of SP in catch block, I have created dynamic string for parameter. However, when it inserts into table, it inserts the string instead of the value of the parameter. below is my code:
DECLARE @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(4000),
@ErrorSeverity INT,
@ErrorState INT,
        @ErrorProcedure VARCHAR(200),
        @ErrorLine INT,
        @ErrorNumber INT,
        @ErrorParams VARCHAR(MAX)='';

-- Get the error information
SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
SET @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
SET @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
SET @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();
SET @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER();

DECLARE @SPParameter AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ParaName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @SPParameter (ParaName)
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.parameters 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(@ErrorProcedure)

DECLARE @minId INT, @maxId INT
SELECT @minId = MIN(Id),@maxId = MAX(Id) FROM @SPParameter

SET @ErrorParams = ''''

WHILE @minId <= @maxId
BEGIN
    SELECT @ErrorParams = @ErrorParams + ''+ParaName+' = ''+ISNULL(CAST('+CAST(ParaName AS varchar)+' AS VARCHAR),'''')+'', '
    FROM @SPParameter WHERE Id=@minId
    SET @minId = @minId + 1
END

SET @ErrorParams = LEFT(@ErrorParams, LEN(@ErrorParams) - 2)

SET @ErrorParams = @ErrorParams + ''''''

INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorMessage, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorProcedure, ErrorLine, ErrorNumber, ErrorParams)
VALUES (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine, @ErrorNumber, @ErrorParams);


It is inserting string I have created dynamically. below is the string which is inserting into my log table:
'@Param1 = '+ISNULL(CAST(@Param1 AS VARCHAR),'') +
  ', @Param2 = '+ISNULL(CAST(@Param2 AS VARCHAR),'') +
  ', @Param3 = '+ISNULL(CAST(@Param3 AS VARCHAR),'') +
  ', @Param4 = '+ISNULL(CAST(@Param4 AS VARCHAR),''


You can't do this "getting parameters dynamically" thing. What you can do is some template code which generates the actual logging code for the specific parameters of each procedure

I am honestly not sure I understand what the above is trying to achieve. Perhaps a [mre] would help here.

can you tell me what am i doing wrong in above code?

He wants to have a generic logging in a procedure which fetches parameters and their values automatically. this is impossible

I am trying to log stored procedure parameter in catch block. I have many parameter in procedure hence i don't want to add each one of them manually. I have created string dynamically. string is properly created but instead of values it has the parameter names in it. I want values of parameter. I hope now it would be clear @ThomA

@siggemannen, can you tell what am i doing wrong in above code

" I have many parameter in procedure hence i don't want to add each one of them manually." That's the problem then... That's what you need to do. Can you give a good reason for why you "don't want to"? You probably spent more time writing this post and comments that it would have taken you to write out the values for the parameters, so i assume there's a different reason.

@ChaitanyaParikh yes, everything. What you want is impossible to achieve

"can you tell what am i doing wrong in above code" The problem is you're trying to do this dynamically, not literally.

@siggemannen Appreciate your feedback and spending time on my question however there are thousands of procedure with different parameter in each. I am very close but i could be missing something and that's where I want your input

yes because there are thousands of procedure and n number of parameter in each one of them

And in each procedure you need to write your own solution, @ChaitanyaParikh ... There is no magic "Concatenate all the parameter values into a string" or "INSERT all the parameter values into a table" feature. If you need the value of @MyParameter in a statement, you need to reference @MyParameter. If you then have a different procedure with a parameter called @AnotherParameter, you need to reference @AnotherParameter. There's no @{First Ordinal Parameter}, @{Infer what I need}, etc syntax.

I want parameter for further debugging what caused the issue. feel free if you have any other solution. except trace, sql profiler

Lite i wrote, what you can do is write a code that generates the final logging string and then put the actual logging string in each procedure, either by using some regex or parsing or manually. Do you really have thousands of procedures with try/catch? Anyway, this code you're working on still needed to be added to each procedure, even if were working

"feel free if you have any other solution" Write the T-SQL you need, for each procedure. Presumably you're part of a team, and presumably your database is source controlled, so as a team you'll be able to work through this task together, to achieve a (somewhat) timely deployment.

It was a good try. You have created a dynamic SQL expression that would work if there were only a way to evaluate it in the current context, but SQL server have no such capability. The EXEC statement can be used to execute dynamic SQL, but it executes in a context where the referenced stored procedure parameters are no longer available.

To achieve your goal, you might be able to write your stored procedures with an initial code fragment like DECLARE @ErrorParams VARCHAR(MAX) = '';. You could then write and execute code that retrieves, analyzes, and alters those procedures to replace this fragment with something like DECLARE @ErrorParams VARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('@Parm1=', @Parm1, ', @Parm2=', @Parm2, ...);.

@TN thank you, could you help me with few lines of code snippets

Why don't you just use XEvents to do all this logging? See eg https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/

If this does not work than I will check other options

Disclaimer: I do not necessarily recommend this approach for general use, but I am posting this as an alternative to what the original poster was attempting to accomplish in the above question.
To achieve your goal, you can write your stored procedures with an initial code fragment like:
DECLARE @ErrorParams VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @ErrorParams = 'Not yet customized';

You can then run a process against all defined stored procedure definitions to replace the above code fragment with something like:
SET @ErrorParams = CONCAT('@Parm1=', @Parm1, ', ', '@Parm2=', @Parm2, ...);

The following logic will accomplish this using a cursor loop to:

Retrieve each stored procedure definition.
Locate the SET @ErrorParams = ...; statement.
Replace it with an expression to build a list of the actual stored procedure parameter names and values.
Change the initial CREATE PROC(edure) statement to an ALTER PROC(edure) statrement, if necessary.
Reapply the modified definition.

The following may not be 100% ready for prime time, but it is a start. I recommend that you script out and safely store away the original stored procedures before applying this process, in case you have a misplaced ';' or if something else goes wrong.
DECLARE CSR CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT P.object_id, P.name, D.Definition
    FROM sys.procedures P
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(P.object_id) AS Definition) D
    WHERE P.name LIKE 'Proc%'
    AND D.Definition LIKE '%SET @ErrorParams =%;%'
OPEN CSR

DECLARE @ObjectId INT
DECLARE @Name SYSNAME
DECLARE @Definition NVARCHAR(MAX)

FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @ObjectId, @Name, @Definition
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartPos INT = CHARINDEX('SET @ErrorParams =', @Definition)
    DECLARE @EndPos INT = CHARINDEX(';', @Definition, @StartPos)
    DECLARE @Length INT = @EndPos - @StartPos + 1

    DECLARE @ErrorParamsList NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
        -- '@Parm1=', @Parm1, ', ', '@Parm2=', @Parm2, ', ', '@Parm3=', @Parm3, ...'
        SELECT STRING_AGG(I.Item, ', '', '', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY PRM.parameter_id)
        FROM sys.parameters PRM
        JOIN sys.types T
            ON T.user_type_id = PRM.user_type_id
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                CASE 
                WHEN T.name = 'xml' -- Explicit conversion needed
                    THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + PRM.name + ')'
                WHEN T.name in ('binary', 'varbinary') -- Custom conversion
                    THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + PRM.name + ', 2)'
                WHEN T.name in ('datetime', 'datetime2') -- Custom conversion
                    THEN 'CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), ' + PRM.name + ', 21)'
                -- ... Handle other custom or unsupported cases
                ELSE PRM.name -- Default conversion handled by CONCAT()
                END AS Expression
        ) E
        CROSS APPLY (
            -- '@ParmN=, @ParmN'
            -- TODO: Special handling for certain parameter types (binary, table, geo?)
            SELECT QUOTENAME(PRM.name + '=', '''') + ', ' + E.Expression AS Item
        ) I
        WHERE PRM.object_id = @ObjectId
    )

    DECLARE @ErrorParamsStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) =
        'SET @ErrorParams = CONCAT(' + @ErrorParamsList + ');'
  
    DECLARE @UpdatedDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
        = STUFF(@Definition, @StartPos, @Length, @ErrorParamsStatement)

    -- The original definition might be a CREATE PROC (or PROCEDURE)
    -- Change to an ALTER. Only one space is allowed after the CREATE.
    -- *** This is *not* entirely safe, if the code contains other "CREATE PROC" content.
    SET @UpdatedDefinition = REPLACE(@UpdatedDefinition, 'CREATE PROC', 'ALTER PROC')

    PRINT ''
    PRINT 'Procedure Name: ' + OBJECT_NAME(@ObjectId)
    PRINT 'ErrorParamsList: ' + @ErrorParamsList
    PRINT 'ErrorParamsStatement: ' + @ErrorParamsStatement
    PRINT 'Updated Definition:' + CHAR(10) + @UpdatedDefinition

    EXEC (@UpdatedDefinition)

    FETCH NEXT FROM CSR INTO @ObjectId, @Name, @Definition
END
  
CLOSE CSR
DEALLOCATE CSR

Although statement terminators (;) are generally optional in SQL Server, the above logic requires its presence.
For some parameter types, explicit or custom conversions and needed. The above only covers a few, but there may be other cases requiring customization. If you use table parameters or user-defined types, those may require special handling.
Null values show as empty values. Strings, XML, and other values that might normally be quoted in code, are not quoted in the above implementation.
Strings containing newlines may show across multiple lines in your logs. You might want to read up on "log injection" and decide if this is a concern.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

thanks a lot for the time you spent on making this code. It took me a while to understand what you have done. You are altering existing SP and adding concatenated string though cursor. Now I understand why you said it is not recommended approach. I am also not comfortable with this mechanism however you gave me nice idea about what other things I could do with this code. My original problem is still there. how to evaluate string i have generated.
